# IndexError: tuple index out of range while running both rasa shell and actions.py file

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

This is my actions.py file :-

from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet
import json

class ActionHr(Action):
def name(self):
print('in self method')
return 'action_leave'

```
def run (self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    print('in run method')
    i = tracker.get_slot('name')
    print(i)
    with open('data1.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.loads(json_file.read())
        
        for result in data['current']:
            print('name'+ result['name'])
            if result['name'].lower() == i.lower():
                print('name Found')
                name = result['name']
                SickLeave = result['Sick Leaves']
                CasualLeave = result['Casual Leaves']
                TotalLeave = result['Total Leaves']
                LeavesLeft = result['Leaves Left']
    response ="""The Leaves left for name {} is {} . You took {} casual leaves and {} sick leaves.""".format(SickLeave,CasualLeave,TotalLeave)
    
    print(response)
                    
    dispatcher.utter_message(response)
    return [SlotSet('name',i)]
```

and this is my json file :

{
"current":
[
{
"name": "Vedant",
"Sick Leaves": 3,
"Casual Leaves": 1,
"Total Leaves": 4,
"Leaves Left": 14
},
{
"name": "Debasmita",
"Sick Leaves": 1,
"Casual Leaves": 5,
"Total Leaves": 6,
"Leaves Left": 12
},
{
"name": "Akoparna",
"Sick Leaves": 4,
"Casual Leaves": 2,
"Total Leaves": 6,
"Leaves Left": 12
},
{
"name": "Ankita",
"Sick Leaves": 1,
"Casual Leaves": 0,
"Total Leaves": 1,
"Leaves Left": 17
},
{
"name": "Sana",
"Sick Leaves": 0,
"Casual Leaves": 6,
"Total Leaves": 6,
"Leaves Left": 12
}
]
}

when I am running both rasa run actions and rasa shell , I am getting this error when I'm trying to get the leave details for the input name ..

Here is my error :

in run method
Debasmita
nameVedant
nameDebasmita
name Found
nameAkoparna
nameAnkita
nameSana
Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://localhost:5055/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\debasmita\anaconda3\envs\hr\lib\site-packages\sanic\app.py", line 976, in handle_request
response = await response
File "c:\users\debasmita\anaconda3\envs\hr\lib\site-packages\rasa_sdk\endpoint.py", line 102, in webhook
result = await executor.run(action_call)
File "c:\users\debasmita\anaconda3\envs\hr\lib\site-packages\rasa_sdk\executor.py", line 387, in run
events = action(dispatcher, tracker, domain)
File "E:\New\actions.py", line 57, in run
response ="""The Leaves left for name {} is {} . You took {} casual leaves and {} sick leaves.""".format(SickLeave,CasualLeave,TotalLeave)
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the line where you try to 'format' the result:

```
response ="""The Leaves left for name {} is {} . You took {} casual leaves and {} sick leaves.""".format(SickLeave,CasualLeave,TotalLeave)
```

Please notice that you have 4 curly brackets and just 3 arguments, so the replacement process using 'format' can not be completed, I reproduced the error as follow:

[image]

Please try to add the missing argument to see if the error persists.